# Get all Caterory values from a column

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate

NHibernate.
I need get all the values from a column categories from a sql data base.

I need put in a List, and return it.

I have this:

```
    public IList<Movie> GetMovieCategories() 
    {
        using (ISession session = NHibernateSessionBuilder.OpenSession()) 
        {
            return session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Movie)).List<Movie>();
        }
    }
```

the problem whith this is that return all the table "Movie", and I need only the column "Category".

How can I do this??

Comment: NHibernate is made to work on objects, not columns of tables. But maybe you can give it a hint that you only want one member.

Comment: do you have an idea in code this?

Comment: Is category an entity or a string?

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do something like this (assuming category is a string):

```
public IList<string> GetMovieCategories() 
{
    using (ISession session = NHibernateSessionBuilder.OpenSession()) 
    {
        return session.QueryOver<Movie>()
               .Select(c => c.Category)
               .List<string>();
    }
}
```

This is also assuming you are using nhibernate 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public IList<string> GetMovieCategories() 
{
    using (ISession session = NHibernateSessionBuilder.OpenSession()) 
    {
        return session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Movie)).SetProjection(Projections.Property("Category")).List<string>();
    }
}
```